# GAE Cursors not working on queries using IN, what's the workaround?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, objectify

I'm trying to execute a fairly complex query against GAE's datastore, basically, a subscriber can subscribe to news from a specific town or any town (*), a specific country or any country (*), specific ... or any ... (*)

Now when I want to notify subscribers about news from ZA, I need to find all subscribers that matches country=ZA as well as those matching country=* and the same for the other fields.

```
Query<Subscriber> query = ofy().load().type(Subscriber.class);

    query  = query.filter("searchCategory IN", Arrays.asList(new String[]{"*", category}));
    query = query.filter("searchCity IN", Arrays.asList(new String[]{"*", city}));
    query = query.filter("searchSuburb IN", Arrays.asList(new String[]{"*", suburb}));
    query = query.filter("searchTown IN", Arrays.asList(new String[]{"*", town}));
    query = query.filter("searchProvince IN", Arrays.asList(new String[]{"*", province}));
    query = query.filter("searchCountry IN", Arrays.asList(new String[]{"*", country}));
    query = query.limit(100);

    QueryResultIterator<Subscriber> iterator = query.iterator();
    while (iterator.hasNext()) {
        Subscriber subscriber = iterator.next();
        System.out.println(iterator.getCursor().toWebSafeString()); // exception here
    }
```

I'm using task queues to notify enormous amounts of subscribers at a time, 100 at a time (anywhere between 20k and 2M results depending on the query) and cursors seemed like the logical way to break down the massive number of results in manageable chunks ... until I ran the application and got a Null Pointer Exception attempting to get the cursor - turned out that cursors aren't supported when using the IN statement.

> Because the NOT_EQUAL and IN operators are implemented with multiple
>   queries, queries that use them do not support cursors, nor do
>   composite queries constructed with the CompositeFilterOperator.or
>   method.

What is the alternative in this situation seeing that I can't use cursors?

Comment: Im facing a similar issue, only in my query there is an importance to the order of results. Im breaking my head thinking of a way i can use cursors with 'IN' query and 'ORDER BY'. If you can think of something i would be happy to hear. Thanks.

Comment: I solved my problem by generating all the permutations of the query and throwing each of them on a task queue as a separate query. I don't think that'll work for sorting unless each task queue inserts that data into a new "table" and does a simple sort and select on that data after all the tasks have completed - very messy!
The search API might be a better option as Patrick have mentioned below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option is to run each of these queries independently using only equals. This would allow you to only grab some entries, however in addition to the cursor you would have to remember which query you are running. This also wouldn't handle de-duplication for you -- which could be a dealbreaker if you are sending out notifications.

You should consider looking into the [prospective search API](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/prospectivesearch/). This is an experimental feature, but it does exactly what you want to do.

The basic idea is that for each user you specify their subscription queries (such as `searchCountry=NZ`, then when you process a news article and send it to the *prospective search API*, it can give you all the subscriptions (queries) which match that article.

Comment: There's about 10 parameters on which I need to search, if I need to check for * and the value for different parameters, that's 2^10 = 1024 different queries I need to run. I've designed a special task queue on the whiteboard this morning to generate these 1024 different queries which in theory won't have duplicates, but will keep it as a last resort as it's a bit nasty to implement.
Will have a look at the search API, thanks!

Comment: Ya that makes sense, having to manage that sounds painful. Remember though that what is happening with NOT_EQUAL and IN queries is essentially this splitting in the client library -- so you'd still end up issuing this number of queries which will definitely lead to scaling issues down the road.

Comment: I've implemented it using a binary number. Since my IN queries all only have two paramaters (except for one), if the binary number was 0, then do an AND query using the first paramater, else do an AND query using the second IN paramater. This way I'm covering all the combinations. The starting process happens inside a task queue, then runs through all these combinations and just passes those params on to a task queue (eg 1: city=*,country=za, 2: city=abc,country=za, 3: city=abc,country=*) thanks to splitting each param combination off to a separate task queue, the search runs concurrently :-D

Answer (score 2):

I think you can use the cursors , according to the documentation

> Some NDB queries don't support query cursors, but you can fix them.
>   If a query uses IN, OR, or !=, then the query results won't work with
>   cursors unless ordered by key. If an application doesn't order the
>   results by key and calls fetch_page(), it gets a BadArgumentError. If
>   User.query(User.name.IN(['Joe',
>   'Jane'])).order(User.name).fetch_page(N) gets an error, change it to
>   User.query(User.name.IN(['Joe', 'Jane'])).order(User.name, User.key).fetch_page(N)

and i suggest you to switch to NDB as its faster and have automatic caching

Comment: I'm already using objectify which has caching as well, switching to NDB is not an option at the moment. 
Will try sorting the output by key / id, if that works then I'm sorted.